# Understanding memory_order_relaxed

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, relaxed-atomics

I am trying to understand the specifics of memory_order_relaxed. I am referring to this link : [CPP Reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order).

```
#include <future>
#include <atomic>

std::atomic<int*> ptr {nullptr};

void fun1(){
        ptr.store(new int{0}, std::memory_order_relaxed);
}

void fun2(){
        while(!ptr.load(std::memory_order_relaxed));
}

int main(){
        std::async(std::launch::async, fun1);
        std::async(std::launch::async, fun2);
}
```

Question 1: In the code above, is it technically possible for fun2 to be in an infinite loop where it sees the value of ptr as nullptr even if the thread that sets ptr has finished running?

If suppose, I change the code above to something like this instead:

```
#include <future>
#include <atomic>

std::atomic<int> i {0};
std::atomic<int*> ptr {nullptr};

void fun1(){
        i.store(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
        i.store(2, std::memory_order_relaxed);
        ptr.store(new int{0}, std::memory_order_release);

}

void fun2(){
        while(!ptr.load(std::memory_order_acquire));
        int x = i.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
}

int main(){
        std::async(std::launch::async, fun1);
        std::async(std::launch::async, fun2);
}
```

Related Question: Is it possible in the code above for fun2 to see the value of atomic i as 1 or is it assured that it will see the value 2?

Comment: Memory ordering has nothing to do with propagation, only with ordering. C++ does in fact not guarantee that changes to memory *ever* become visible to other threads. What ordering says is that *if* you observe a memory update, *then* you can conclude that other effects (those previous to the update) will also be observed.

Comment: So in effect it means that the answer to my first question is that it is possible for fun2 to be in an infinite loop (even if i had used some stronger memory ordering like seq_cst) and the answer to my second question is that it is guaranteed that the value of i will be 2 because the previous memory update to ptr is visible

Comment: I think there's nothing in the Standard that guarantees that the loop terminates, but of course it *will* on every real platform. The Standard contains a note that says "please propagate this in reasonable time".

Comment: Thanks Kerrek SB. The reason why I had this doubt was because the said link above mentions that when we use memory_order_relaxed, a  thread will see some value that it had seen in the past or a later value but never a value that comes before a value already seen in the modification order of the variable. It also mentions that when we use memory_order_relaxed, it is possible to keep seeing the same value again and again and that there is no obligation for it to return values later in the modification order. But according to you this may be the case with a stringent memory_order as well and

Comment: that this has got nothing to do with the memory order but the standard expects implementations to propagate the changes in a reasonable time for all memory order constraints.

Comment: I was confused by the same thing and was about to post my own question.  My understanding has always been that there is no **guarantee** that changes will be published to other threads without some kind of synchronization, but some discussions of the C++11 memory model seem to imply otherwise.  I understand that, in practice, changes will **eventually** be published due to how the hardware operates, but this is kind of glossed over in those same sources.  Thanks @KerrekSB!  Please answer this question so I can upvote it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

An interesting observation is that, with your code, there is no actual concurrency; i.e. `fun1` and `fun2` run sequentially, the reason being that, under specific conditions (including calling `std::async` with the `std::launch::async` launch policy), the `std::future` object returned by `std::async` has its destructor block until the launched function call returns. Since you disregard the return object, its destructor is called before the end of the statement. Had you reversed the two statements in `main()` (i.e. launch `fun2` before `fun1`), your program would have been caught in an infinite loop since `fun1` would never run.

This `std::future` wait-upon-destruction behavior is somewhat controversial (even within the standards committee) and since I assume you didn't mean that, I will take the liberty to rewrite the 2 statements in `main` for (both examples) to:

```
auto tmp1 = std::async(std::launch::async, fun1);
auto tmp2 = std::async(std::launch::async, fun2);
```

This will defer the actual `std::future` return object destruction till the end of `main` so that `fun1` and `fun2` get to run asynchronously.

> is it technically possible for fun2 to be in an infinite loop where it sees the value of ptr as nullptr even if the thread that sets ptr has finished running?

No, this is not possible with `std::atomic` (on a real platform, as was mentioned in the comments section). With a non-`std::atomic` variable, the compiler could (theoretically) have chosen to keep the value in register only, but a `std::atomic` is stored and cache coherency will propagate the value to other threads. Using `std::memory_order_relaxed` is fine here as long as you don't dereference the pointer.

> Is it possible in the code above for fun2 to see the value of atomic i as 1 or is it assured that it will see the value 2?

It is guaranteed to see value 2 in variable `x`.
`fun1` stores two different values to the same variable, but since there is a clear dependency, these are not reordered.

In `fun1`, the `ptr.store` with `std::memory_order_release` prevents the `i.store(2)` with `std::memory_order_relaxed` from moving down below its release barrier. In `fun2`, the `ptr.load` with `std::memory_order_acquire` prevents the `i.load` with `std::memory_order_relaxed` from moving up across its acquire barrier. This guarantees that `x` in `fun2` will have value 2.

Note that by using `std::memory_order_relaxed` on *all* atomics, it would be possible to see `x` with value 0, 1 or 2, depending on the relative ordering of access to atomic variable `i` with regards to `ptr.store` and `ptr.load`.

Comment: "Using std::memory_order_relaxed is fine here as long as you don't dereference the pointer.". Is this because the `atomic` itself has been updated to hold the pointer value, but the memory block allocated by new might not yet be allocated/or might not yet be "released" into the memory ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @george_ptr Yes, that is exactly the reason

Comment: std::memory_order_release make sure no reads or writes in the current thread can be reordered after this store, but it cannot make sure the order of `i.store(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);` and `i.store(2, std::memory_order_relaxed);`. If these two store operations are reordered, is it possible that the value of i is 1 before ptr.store?

Comment: @Peipei No this is not possible because all threads observe changes to a _single_ variable in the same order (aka modification order).
Since the releasing thread writes 1 to `i` followed by 2, all threads will see that.