# Uses of memory_order_relaxed

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic

There are already a few questions on Stackoverflow that essentially ask about the use cases of `memory_order_relaxed`, such as:

[Understanding memory_order_relaxed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31150809/understanding-memory-order-relaxed)

[What are some use cases for memory_order_relaxed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23487372/what-are-some-use-cases-for-memory-order-relaxed)

However, I'm still confused about the precise semantics of `memory_order_relaxed`.  Generally, the example use case for `memory_order_relaxed` is something like `std::shared_ptr` - basically it keeps an atomic counter, but it doesn't need to sync with other threads.

Okay, so my understanding is as follows:

`std::memory_order_relaxed`, when used with `load()` only guarantees that the thread which loads it will do so atomically - it makes no guarantee about any orderings with respect to other threads that do `store()` operations on the same variable, and it makes absolutely no guarantee about any loads/stores of non-atomic variables (i.e. no memory fence will be generated.)

But does `memory_order_relaxed` provide ANY sort of "happens-before" type ordering ability, with regard *only* to the single atomic value?  For example, if we have:

```
std::atomic_flag x = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT;

// Thread A:
//
if (!x.test_and_set(std::memory_order_relaxed)) {
   std::cout << "Thread A got here first!" << std::endl;
}

// Thread B:
//
if (!x.test_and_set(std::memory_order_relaxed)) {
   std::cout << "Thread B got here first!" << std::endl;
}
```

In the above example, even though we used `memory_order_relaxed`, haven't we also provided a guaranteed way to reason about ordering here?  In other words, both Thread A and Thread B will be able to reason about which thread set the flag first.  It's just that, due to the relaxed ordering, neither thread A nor thread B will be able to assume anything about the values of any surrounding *non-atomic* shared variables, since there is no memory fence. Or am I incorrect here?

Comment: `test_and_set` is read-modify-write operation, and as I understand when it succeeds - it always acts on "last" value, i.e. only one thread will change it from "0" to "1" . So perhaps you should use other example. Also refer slide 14 [here](https://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk//files/safety_off.pdf).

Comment: Two threads can change it from "0" to "1". Another thread might be clearing it. But I agree that an increment would have been a better example.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Of course, but not in this case - there is no `clear`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're correct. And as you noted, there are use cases (such as a counter) where that's fine.